# Preview post when using custom post page

Tags: previews

I've got a custom user post page, where my users can post, but I'm missing a preview option, where the user can preview their post before they are posting it..

Preferable if it opens in a pop-up or new page, so the content users has written doesn't disappear.

Is there any function like that?

Edit:

I'm pretty new to this, and I've searched around, explored a few plugin
Plugins that have some kind of preview function to try to understand how it works, but I'm clueless..

Comment: No one? There must be some function too call a preview..

Comment: Please update your question to include details about steps you've already taken and research you've already done. Please review https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask if you need help fleshing out your question.